# Randomized stochastic gradient descent algorithm for nonconvex optimization

Tags: optimization, stochastic-analysis, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

In [Stochastic First-and Zeroth-order Methods for Nonconvex](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5549.pdf) page 5, we have the following algorithm:

[image]
I am trying to implement this algorithm with constant a stepsize which makes $P_R$ to be a uniform distribution. I am having trouble how it works at the third main line where we have $\textbf{Step} \quad k= 1, \cdots, R$. At this line, we need to pick $R$ randomly so suppose $N=1000$, and $R$ take on $3$ as its value. Do we have to do $3$ stochastic gradient descent and we are done?

Comment: This is common in stochastic gradient methods. Notice that the guarantees for this method are given *in expectation*, so averaging over all possible values $R$ could take. Indeed, if you want a high probability statement, you have to repeatedly call the RSG method (Eq. (2.20) in your paper).

Comment: @VHarisop: Thank you for the reply. However, I have difficulty on showing the bound in (2.20). I do not know how to derive it? Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with VHarisop's answer. Using equation 2.20 in the paper, you will find an approximate $N$ which then can be used to give you the accuracy you are looking for. Obviously, you have to call the RSG algorithm not one time but rather many times as you can find the relevant information in the paragraph right under where they define the RSG algorithm.

For more information, refer to this post where I provided a brief proof of getting equation 2.20 in the paper ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608920/number-of-calls-to-oracle-in-randomized-stochastic-gradient-rsg-algorithm)). Good luck.